# When I run nest.js, I get a Missing "driver" option error

Tags: graphql, nestjs, prisma

I am using nest.js, prisma, and graphql.
When I run the npm run start:dev command, I get an error.
If anyone knows how to solve this, please let me know.

> ERROR [GraphQLModule] Missing
> "driver" option. In the latest version of "@nestjs/graphql" package
> (v10) a new required configuration property called "driver" has been
> introduced. Check out the official documentation for more details on
> how to migrate (https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/migration-guide).
> Example:

GraphQLModule.forRoot({
driver: ApolloDriver,
})

```
app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } from 'apollo-server-core';
import { DonationsModule } from './donations/donations.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      playground: false,
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
    }),
    DonationsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
generate-typings.ts
import { GraphQLDefinitionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { join } from 'path';

const definitionsFactory = new GraphQLDefinitionsFactory();
definitionsFactory.generate({
  typePaths: ['./src/**/*.graphql'],
  path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.ts'),
  outputAs: 'class',
  watch: true,
});
```

fix

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
    }),
    DonationsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checkout the nestjs/graphql documentation [page](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start) and the other [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/migration-guide) that you have mentioned. You have to configure your `GraphQLModule` like this which I don't see in your code.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
    }),
  ],
})
```

Comment: I rewrote it as above. (fix)
The following error occurs at the location import { ApolloDriverConfig, ApolloDriver } from '@nestjs/apollo';.

Comment: Cannot find module '@nestjs/apollo' or corresponding type declaration. ts(2307)

Comment: Have you installed @nestjs/apollo? @yuturo

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget to import

```
import { ApolloDriverConfig, ApolloDriver } from '@nestjs/apollo';
```